# Convert File If Not Exists

Tags: bash, file, scripting

I am attempting to write a `bash` script.  What I am wanting is the following

> 1) Scan the directory recursively for all `.mkv` files
>   2) **IF** `.mkv` file is found check 
>   
>   a) if `.mkv` file is in use
>            i) if yes leave the directory
>            ii) if no continue to process
>         b) check if **CURRENT** directory has a `.mp4`
>   
>      i) if yes do 
>            ii) if no convert to `.mp4`
>   
> 3) Scan next directory

This is my current script, and *I THINK* I have all the elements in play except for two pieces

> 1) Capture current directory
> 2) Check if current directory has a `.mp4`

I tried using the `$PWD` command to capture current directory, but it would always only return this directory `/home/omartinez/Downloads`

What must I do to accomplish my 2 unknown steps above?

```
#/bin/sh
#recursive file search

#setting the directory to scan and filetype to scan for
for f in $(find /home/omartinez/Downloads) -name '*mkv' );
do
  #checking if the file is open
  if lsof $f
  then
    #this file is in use
  else
    #the file is closed and can be converted
    avconv -i $f.mkv -codec copy $f.mp4 
  fi
done
```

EDIT --

Per the suggestion of @M. Hicklen below I modified my code to this (attempting to use that answer)

```
#/bin/sh
#recursive file search
for file in $(find /home/omartinez/Downloads -type f -name "*.mkv")
do
  if lsof $f
  then
    #this file is in use
    else
      find /home/owner/Downloads -wholename "$(echo ${file} | perl -pe 's|(.*)/(.*).mkv$|\1/\2.mp4|')" > /dev/null
      || convert ${file} $(echo ${file} | perl -pe 's|(.*)/(.*).mkv$|\1/\2.mp4|')
fi
```

done

However, this produces an error of:

> ./search: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
>   ./search: line 16:`    || convert ${file} $(echo ${file} | perl -pe 's|(.*)/(.*).mkv$|\1/\2.mp4|')'

I am sure this is 100% on me, but can someone point out what I did incorrectly?

EDIT ---

Using the suggestion below by @jil it recursively scans my entire system not just the location listed.  I verified this by watching it scan directories such as

> /usr/
>   /firefox
>   
> /Teamviewer 
>   
> etc

This is the syntax I used:

`for file in $(find /home/omartinez/Downloads -type f -name "*.mkv"); do
    mp4=${file%.mkv}.mp4
     if ! lsof $f && [ ! -e "$mp4" ]; then
        convert $file $mp4
     fi
    done`

Is there a way to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.mkv")
do
    find . -wholename "$(echo ${file} | perl -pe 's|(.*)/(.*).mkv$|\1/\2.mp4|')" > /dev/null
    || convert ${file} $(echo ${file} | perl -pe 's|(.*)/(.*).mkv$|\1/\2.mp4|')
done
```

- find file ending in .mkv and set to variable
- send filename to perl to strip path; locate locate mp4 version and discard result
- if no mp4 found, use filename and strip path to convert mkv version to mp4

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error `./search: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token else` is caused by the empty `if` clause. Try:

```
 if ! lsof $f
    find ...
 fi
```

if you do not want to do anything in the case when the file is in use.

Overall your solution seems over complicated. Something like:

```
for file in $(find /home/omartinez/Downloads -type f -name "*.mkv"); do
    mp4=${file%.mkv}.mp4
    if ! lsof $f && [ ! -e "$mp4" ]; then
        convert $file $mp4
    fi
done
```

Comment: I watch terminal lines and it go through Teamviewer dir, then firefox dir, then /usr dir.  It is for certain scanning all directories.